# Filebeat processor script per index

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

How can I specify which Elastic index the Filebeat processor script should apply to?
I am talking about this processor script https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-script.html but I don't see the option to specify index anywhere.

I have indexes "firewall' and "switch" and I want to apply script A only to messages sent to "firewall" index and script B only to messages sent to "switch" index.
So far, I have only managed to apply the scripts to ALL the messages (globally), but this means it applies script A to "switch" too and I do not want that.

Is there also a performance impact for applying scripts to all indexes vs applying scripts to specific indexes (if that is possible)?

**EDIT**
After trying Val's solution, I came to this:

```
processors:
  - script:
      when:
        equals:
          _index: "firewall-11.2021"
      lang: javascript
      id: my_filter1
      file: ${path.config}/Script_A.js
```

The _index field in messages is exactly "firewall-11.2021" so it should run script_A for messages having _index = "firewall-11.2021" (aka messages sent to "firewall-11.2021" index) but it does not. If I remove the condition, Script_A runs but for all messages.

This is the _index field I am placing a condition on:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [define conditions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/defining-processors.html) under which a given processor should be run or not. So in your case, it would look like this:

```
processors:
  - script:
      when:
        equals:
          _index: 'firewall'
      id: script_A
  - script:
      when:
        equals:
          _index: 'switch'
      id: script_B
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, I was on PTO. I tried this but no success. The condition does not seem to be satisfied, since the script processor i'm testing runs without it. Check my question for edits.

Comment: I don't think you need to include the date suffix `-11.2021` because that's not known until the document leaves Filebeat.

Comment: This is how I declare my index:
index: "firewall_index-%{[agent.version]}-%{+YYYY.MM}"

So condition should be _index: 'firewall_index-'? I don't know how to handle the dashes in it.

I tried
when:
        contains:
          _index: "firewall_index"

But it still does not pass the condition.

Comment: I think that configuration is not taken into account because your index in Kibana shows up as `firewall-11.2021`, so something doesn't add up

Comment: I renamed the indexes to dummy names for this question if that's what you're asking. 
"firewall_index-%{[agent.version]}-%{+YYYY.MM}" would give "firewall_index-7.15.1-2021.11" in this case.

Comment: Gotcha. My other question is how is the index branching done at the output level? How does Filebeat decides to send to the firewall index vs the switch one?

Comment: It uses a "tags" field to decide the index such as:

indices:
    - index: "firewall-%{[agent.version]}-%{+YYYY.MM}"
      when.contains:
            tags: "firewall"
And I ended up using the field "tags" instead of index and got the same result. Thank you for your help! :)